# Django: mysql query with arguments

Tags: mysql, django, string-formatting

i have a MySQL query like this

```
cursor.execute("GRANT USAGE ON %s.* TO %s@%s", [db, user, host])
```

Python generate a query like

```
GRANT USAGE ON 'db'.* TO 'user'@'host';
```

But the apostrophes around 'db' are not allowed in MySQL. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to get around this.

```
grant = "GRANT USAGE ON %s.* TO '%s'@'%s'" % [db, user, host]
cursor.execute(grant)
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks. Are the arguments safe for mysql injections with this method?

Comment: It's not bullet proof - but these are typically not coming from an end user generated data.